# My Weather Api doesn't work on another device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing the Local Weather. When I test it, it worked on my Android device and my Laptop. But my Desktop device didn't work, and they're using the same wifi. Sorry for my English.
My HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
      id: "1580578",
      APPID: "1d6bb0530f112b543e38e98b7f2b3d36"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
      var kelvin = data.main.temp;
      var windspeed = data.wind.speed;
      var city = data.name;
      var doC = kelvin - 273;

      $(".name").html(city);
      $(".doC").html(Math.floor(doC));
      $(".windspeed").html(windspeed);
      $(".weatherType").html(weatherType);
      $('.current').html('<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png" /> ' + data.weather[0].main);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/QGsncry.jpg');
}

#white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid>
  <div class=" row ">
    <h1 style="text-align: center" id="white"> Weather</h1>
    <center>
      <div class="current"></div>

      <table style="text-align: center">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h3> Description: </h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3 style="text-align: center" class="weatherType btn btn-default"> </h3>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h3> City: </h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3 style="text-align: center" class="name btn btn-default"> </h3>
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>
            <h3> Temperature: </h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3 style="text-align: center" class="doC btn btn-default"> </h3>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h3> WindSpeed: </h3>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h3 style="text-align: center" class="windspeed btn btn-default"> </h3>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors? How does it "not work"?

Comment: Did you meant to use `td` instead of `th`? Or you did that intentionally?

Comment: `class="container-fluid` is missing the closing quote

Comment: Works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/qO8xLsZiuVcQZ8jWVK9A?p=preview

Comment: I have uploaded it on the  https://testmyblog.000webhostapp.com/. I show my friends and they said the information in the class="name","windspeed" didn't show up. My English is not enough to explain it clearly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `https`.

As you have hosted your app on `https://testmyblog.000webhostapp.com/` **https** and your API is on **http** `http://api.openweathermap.org/` so recent browsers will throw error due to `Mixed Content`. Means if your website is on `HTTPS` you cannot load resources from `http` non-secure domain. This is a browser specific feature and thus, your request is blocked by the browser itself.

So, if your friends are facing any issue.. ask them to load your website without `HTTPS.` Means ask them to load

> http://testmyblog.000webhostapp.com/

instead of https version/

Comment: @Nghĩa Lê ask them to load website with `http` not `https` as your api is on `http`.